# Django - TDD: 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'POST'

Tags: python, django

So I'm doing TDD with Django and I'm stuck on the following problem.

Test method for class from TestCase

```
def test_home_page_can_save_POST_request(self):
    request = HttpRequest
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.POST['item_text'] = 'A new list item'

    response = home_page(request)

    self.assertIn('A new list item', response.content.decode())
```

And I'm getting error as:

```
request.POST['item_text'] = 'A new list item'
AttributeError: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'POST'
```

But HttpRequest has the attribute 'POST' as per Django docs.

Thansk guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses after `HttpRequest` :)

That's why django is saying `HttpRequest has no attribute 'POST'`

Comment: Thanks mate, I've been trying to solve it for couple hours with different modules. Damn these parentheses or semicolons :D

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) for your test cases.

Example from the docs:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser, User
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

from .views import MyView, my_view

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@…', password='top_secret')

    def test_details(self):
        # Create an instance of a GET request.
        request = self.factory.get('/customer/details')

        # Recall that middleware are not supported. You can simulate a
        # logged-in user by setting request.user manually.
        request.user = self.user

        # Or you can simulate an anonymous user by setting request.user to
        # an AnonymousUser instance.
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

        # Test my_view() as if it were deployed at /customer/details
        response = my_view(request)
        # Use this syntax for class-based views.
        response = MyView.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing, if you need a request object, you can also use the request factory to generate one

Reference from the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser, User
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

from .views import MyView, my_view

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@…', password='top_secret')

    def test_details(self):
        # Create an instance of a GET request.
        request = self.factory.get('/customer/details')

        # Recall that middleware are not supported. You can simulate a
        # logged-in user by setting request.user manually.
        request.user = self.user

        # Or you can simulate an anonymous user by setting request.user to
        # an AnonymousUser instance.
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

        # Test my_view() as if it were deployed at /customer/details
        response = my_view(request)
        # Use this syntax for class-based views.
        response = MyView.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

In your case, your test could look like this:

```
from django.test import RequestFactory

...

def test_home_page_can_save_POST_request(self):
    factory = RequestFactory()
    response = factory.post('PATH_TO_YOUR_VIEW', data={
        'item_text': 'A new list item',
    })
    self.assertIn('A new list item', response.content.decode())
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely gonna look into that. So far I'm following a book and learning TDD

Answer (score 0):

I have two solution.

1.- Create request object with RequestFactory and calling at views.

```
def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
    request = self.factory.post("/", data={'item_text': 'A new list item',})
    response = home_page(request)
    self.assertIn('A new list item', response.content.decode())
```

2.- Or use the response of RequestFactory().

```
  def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        response = self.factory.post("/", data={'item_text': 'A new list item',})
        self.assertIn('A new list item', response.readlines()[3].decode())
```